# How to call method with parameters on custom html element Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm having a significant problem with my project.
I have a class "Element" that extends from HTML element and I want to call on it a method insertPill(color) however browser throws an error that insertPill is not a function. What should I do?
I attach the code with simplified version of method

```js
import { XYPosition } from "./ElementPosition.js";
import { PillColor } from './PillColors.js'

export default class Element extends HTMLElement {

    private _positionX: number;
    private _positionY: number;
    private _state: FieldState;
    private _pillColor: PillColor;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._state = FieldState.Empty;
    };

    public set position( object:XYPosition ){
        this._positionX = object.x;
        this._positionY = object.y;
    };

    public get position(): XYPosition {
        return new XYPosition(this._positionX, this._positionY)
    };

    public insertPill( color: PillColor ): any {
        color = PillColor.Yellow;
        this._state = FieldState.Pill;
        this._pillColor = color;
        // document.querySelectorAll("element")[this.positionY].classList.add("yellow")
        this.classList.add("Yellow");
        console.log(this)
    };
    public emptyField(): any {
        this._state = FieldState.Empty;
        this._pillColor = PillColor.None;
        this.classList.remove();
    };
}
enum FieldState {
    Empty,
    Pill,
    Virus,
}
```

And the place where it is called:

```
import { PillColor } from './PillColors.js'
import Element from "./Element.js";

export default class Pill {

    private positionX: number;
    private positionY: number;
    private align: boolean; // true - horizontal | false - vertical
    constructor() {
        this.positionX = 4;
        this.positionY = 0;
        this.align = true;
    }


    public moveRight(){
        this.positionX++;
    }
    public moveDown(){
        this.positionY+=8;
        console.log(`%c ${ this.positionY }  `, 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
        if (this.positionY >= 128) this.positionY = 0;
        // console.log( document.querySelectorAll("element")[0] )
    }

    public startMoving() {
        setInterval( ()=> {
            document.querySelectorAll("element")[this.positionY].classList.remove("yellow")
            document.querySelectorAll("element")[this.positionY+1].classList.remove("blue")
            let old1 = document.querySelectorAll("element")[this.positionY+1] as Element
            // old1.emptyField()
            let old2 = document.querySelectorAll("element")[this.positionY+1] as Element
            // old2.emptyField()

            this.moveDown()


            let el1 : Element = document.querySelectorAll("element")[this.positionY+1] as Element;
            // console.log(el1.position)
            //     el1.insertPill( PillColor.Yellow )
            let el2 : Element = document.querySelectorAll("element")[this.positionY+1] as Element;
                el2.insertPill( PillColor.Blue )



        }, 1000 )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**What went wrong**

You can use `as` in TypeScript to inform TypeScript that an object has a certain type it can't infer.

However this could very well be a lie you tell TypeScript. This is the case here. You are telling TypeScript that an `HTMLElement` should be treated as a `Element`. In reality it is an `HTMLElement` you are dealing with, not an `Element`. `HTMLElement` doesn't have the method you are looking for, so there is a bug.

**Suggestion**

You could pass an html-element in an object. This may work for you depending on your requirements. Code would look something like this:

```
class Element {
  constructor(public html_element: HTMLElement) {}

  public say_hi() {
    console.log("say hi");
  }
}

const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("app");
const element = new Element(appDiv);
element.html_element.innerText = "Hello";
element.say_hi();
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sylnak?file=index.ts